# I Can't Get This Responsive Background Picture To Scroll With The Page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to set up my web page so it has a big responsive picture at the top that scrolls with the page instead of staying fixed.

AN EXACT EXAMPLE OF WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO IS: http://teamtreehouse.com/

Here's my attempt of trying to recreate it. Please help!!

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
        html {
            background: url(https://www.pathful.com/static/images/header/header-bg-home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
     <h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this you are trying to achieve ? :

```
<head>
    <style>

body, html {
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
}

.header { 
  background: url(https://www.pathful.com/static/images/header/header-bg-home.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
  min-height:450px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 class="title">How to make picture scroll with page while keepin the pic responsive?</h1>
<br>
<br>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bGglA

To attach the background to your html-tag was the error.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you so much for your help!!! This is exactly what I was trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You have its attachment set to fixed. Just remove it.

Change

```
background: url(https://www.pathful.com/static/images/header/header-bg-home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

To

```
background: url(https://www.pathful.com/static/images/header/header-bg-home.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the "fixed" attribute in the following CSS line:

```
background: url(https://www.pathful.com/....jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

To have the image scroll with the page, just remove it:

```
background: url(https://www.pathful.com/....jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

To learn more, check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp